# How to set Tinymce Value content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to set my Tinymce value content.
My Html Code is :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="activity">Activity</label>
   <label class="activity-error pull-right text-danger"></label>
   <textarea name="activity" id="activity" class="mceEditor"> </textarea>
</div>
```

And My Script is :

```
tinyMCE.get('activity').setContent('<p>hello world</p>');
```

But It didn't worked. 
What's going on? Please Help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you make an example of your code on TinyMCE Fiddle?  Without seeing running code or a specific error message it would be impossible to answer your question.

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gvgaab/2

Here is my Example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have (based on your Fiddle) is you are trying to use TinyMCE APIs to interact with the editor before its initialized.  I have adjusted your Fiddle here:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gvgaab/3

The net is that you are trying to call `tinymce.get('content')` before TinyMCE completes its initialization.  I have console logged the result and you will see its `null`.  When you try to call `getContent()` on `null` that fails.

TinyMCE provides a hook to know when the editor is fully initialized and my updated Fiddle shows how to use that to trigger loading data into the editor.